# Sci fi novel about a ship in an asteroid with AI, human man and alien crew

Tags: story-identification, novel

A man ends up on a mining/research asteroid lab, his ship is in need of repair and the lab is going to self-destruct or lose all air. An alien female and her child were left there. They find a ship within an asteroid with an active AI. They manage to get the new ship running with air for them all and start a space adventure, populating the ship with alien species as crew.

I read this book from Amazon within the last 5 years or so. I've been looking through all my books and doing google searches to find this book but haven't yet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember what the cover looked like?  You should review the [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: No, I don't remember what the cover looked like unfortunately. Okay, I'll go and review the story-id q's. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Okay I found the book I was looking for. I didn't realize that Amazon does show books that you've returned after borrowing them. It took awhile since I had a lot of books to go through.... the joys of reading.

*[It Ain't Over...](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/44782805)* by Robert M Kerns

> Buy a planet and disappear...
>
> That's all Cole wanted.
>
> He spent thirteen years hiding on the fringes of society, piloting freighters for criminals and building a stash to do just that.
>
> But life happens when you're busy making plans.
>
> When Cole chooses to save an ejected castaway and stumbles into a crew of his own, he starts down a path that will force him to choose.
>
> Will Cole protect those who have become his people? Or will he slip away quietly in the night?

[image: Front cover of It Aint Over...]

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. You will have to wait for 48 hours after asking (normally, it's about 10 minutes, but self-answers are a little different) before you can do so successfully.